# How to test axios requests in react testing library and jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, integration-testing, react-testing-library

so I am trying to test that the onSubmit function is handled like it should be after clicking the search button.

the way I am trying to test this is by testing the internals of the onSubmit function.

so I am basically trying to test the behavior of the axios request. (if it got called successfully)

in the test i mocked the axios request and passed data into it and tried to see if it got called after clicking the search button, for some reason I keep getting an error on this test.

i would appreciate anyone who can help me.

*the test*

```
describe('RecipeSearch', () => {
    test('submit button should return post function to recipes/search/', () => {
        let mock = new MockAdapter(axios);
        userEvent.selectOptions(screen.getByRole('combobox'), 'Sweet');
        userEvent.click(screen.getByText('Search'));

        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        };
        const searchRecipes = mock.onPost(
            `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/recipes/search/`,
            { flavor_type: 'Sweet' },
            { config }
        );
        expect(searchRecipes).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

*the Error*

```
    expect(received).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

    Received has type:  object
    Received has value: {"abortRequest": [Function abortRequest], "abortRequestOnce": [Function abortRequestOnce], "networkError": [Function networkError], "networkErrorOnce": [Function networkErrorOnce], "passThrough": [Function passThrough], "reply": [Function reply], "replyOnce": [Function replyOnce], "timeout": [Function timeout], "timeoutOnce": [Function timeoutOnce]}
```

*the function*

```
const recipeSearch = ({ setRecipes }) => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        flavor_type: 'Sour',
    });

    const { flavor_type } = formData;

    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

    const onChange = (e) => setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });

    const onSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();

        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        };

        setLoading(true);
        axios
            .post(
                `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/recipes/search/`,
                {
                    flavor_type,
                },
                config
            )
            .then((res) => {
                setLoading(false);
                setRecipes(res.data);
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                setLoading(false);
                window.scrollTo(0, 0);
            });
    };

    return (
        <form  onSubmit={(e) => onSubmit(e)}>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor='flavor_type'>Choose Flavor</label>
                        <select
                            name='flavor_type'
                            onChange={(e) => onChange(e)}
                            value={flavor_type}
                        >
                            <option value='Sour'>Sour</option>
                            <option>Sweet</option>
                            <option>Salty</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                            <button type='submit'>Search</button> 
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using [axios-mock-adapter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-mock-adapter). According to the examples on the page, after you create the mock adapter in your test, you need to then mock the call you are making. You are making a POST call in your `onSubmit` so you need something like:

```js
mock.onPost(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/recipes/search/`).reply(function (config) {
  return [
    200,
    {
      recipes: [{ id: 1, name: "Chocolate Cake" }],
    },
  ];
});
```

I'm not sure about the shape of your data, you'd need to match that to your needs.

However, I don't believe you can use the `toHaveBeenCalled()` feature, that is for `jest` mocks and I don't believe it works here. If you prefer that you would need to mock `axios` using [jest](https://www.robinwieruch.de/axios-jest).

I assume you want axios-mock-adapter, then docs say you can verify a call using:

```js
expect(mock.history.post.length).toBe(1);
expect(mock.history.post[0].data).toBe(JSON.stringify([{ id: 1, name: "Chocolate Cake" }]));
```

Comment: thanks for the comment bro :), unfortunately i get an error saying: expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 1
    Received: 0`